# Who would win in a fight an Easter island head or a Spanish Conquistador

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, aliens, weapons

I was having a shower when i suddenly thought of this scenario.

What do you think?

Comment: I think you should make this question more clear

Comment: You might want to check what was coming out with the water in your shower ;-)

Comment: More seriously, I don't think that is about worldbuilding at all.

Answer (score 2):

The fight would result in a draw, as the simple musket and swords of the Conquistador would do little to damage the stone head, while the head has no way of damaging the Conquistador in the first place.

Comment: lol depends on the conditions of the fight.  If it is the last man standing the Conquistador wins instantly as the head can neither be a man or stand.

Comment: @sdrawkcabdear: OTOH, the conquistador will eventually die of old age, while the head will just weather a little :-)

Comment: What if a heavy wind blows the head onto the man?

Comment: @PyRulez Do you have any idea how heavy those heads are! You show me a wind gust large enough to blow one of them over, I'll show you a Conquistador a hundred meters away.

Comment: a local god(ness) could use the "hand of god" and tip it over the attacker when he is trying to impale that head with hit sword...